# Is it necessary to escape user input from Request class?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is something like `cgi.escape()` useful for sanitizing inputs from the [Request](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass) class? I have user input that will be going into the Datastore.

I don't know though if Datastore sanitizes inputs on its own.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the request class? Classes start with uppercases in Java. And why should inputs be sanitized? How do you insert them into the DataStore?

Comment: Request class: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass . I insert them into the datastore as either TextProperty or StringProperty.

Comment: No datastore will not sanitize input. The input could come from any source so it would not know how to sanitize it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to escape the user input before you insert into the Datastore and Webapp2 doesn't have any helper for it.

**cgi.escape()** will work but its not enough.

Good references:

- [Owasp.org ( XSS Prevention )](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)
- [Escaping Html in Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the response -- would something like `json.dumps()` on top of `cgi.escape()` work? From testing a bit in the terminal it seems like those functions together will escape the nasty characters that go into a code block. Thanks.

Comment: im not sure if json.dumps will work as you expect, but you can create your own escape method based on the data that you want to save on the datastore. If you dont need tags in your data you could remove it instead of escape it.